# List within List alteration

Tags: python, list

I have a lists within a list and basically trying to modify all cases where I see a keyword.
For example:

```
test_out = [['I am monkey free.'], ['I explained my life free.']]

A = "monkey free"
```

My goal is that for every instance in the test_out list that I see A = "money free", replace that with "xxxxxx"

The output should then be:

```
test_out = [['I am xxxxxx'], ['I explained my life free.']]
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Money free or monkey free?  There's a difference :)

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
>>> test_out = [['I am monkey free.'], ['I explained my life free.']]
>>> A = "monkey free"
>>> replacement = "xxxxxx"
>>> [[string.replace(A, replacement) for string in sublist] for sublist in test_out]
[['I am xxxxxx.'], ['I explained my life free.']]
```

Do you really want your lists nested two deep, though?

Comment: I messed up by making it two deep in the very beginning so im a little hesitant to tweak right away. I'll flatten it out probably in a few days. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user3116753 Fair enough. If you want to flatten the list, though, it's straightforward: `new_list = [item for sublist in test_out for item in sublist]`.